# doctrine one to one persist id automatically with annotations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, persistence, one-to-one

I have a difficulty which I can't seem to resolve even though it seems I am applying the good recipes other found.

I receive the following error :

> Entity of type AppBundle\Entity\User\Student is missing an assigned ID
>   for field 'user'. The identifier generation strategy for this entity
>   requires the ID field to be populated before EntityManager#persist()
>   is called. If you want automatically generated identifiers instead you
>   need to adjust the metadata mapping accordingly.

I have a doctrine 2 one to one relationship between my entities user and student in symfony 2 and as I persist the user with a subform of student, i would like the id of the student to be automatically set to the id of the user.

I have two classes :

```
class Student
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=11)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\User\User", inversedBy="student")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, unique=true, onDelete="cascade")
     */
    private $user;
...
}


class User
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\User\Student", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $student;
}
```

when I persist the entity, I have the error described above. If I call

> $entity->getStudent()->setUser($entity);

before I persist the entity, it's just fine, I get the student persisted with the same id as the user except I don't want to get specific in the method I use to persist because I use a form manager as a service and it is common to other actions.

So is it possible to set some annotations to get doctrine to automatically set the student id equal to the user id when creating the student ?
If yes, how so ?

Thank you a lot,
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

I have seen you updated your question. I am not quite shure if its possible, but try something like

```
class Student
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false, unique=true)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\User\User", inversedBy="student")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, unique=true, onDelete="cascade")
     */
    private $user;

    // ...
}
```

I went back to using `id` column, but defined it before without automatical increment.

Comment: well, I've tried it and it's not changing, I get the same error. I tried with user_id, with something_id, I've not forgotten to update the database schema, I tried to remove the entire @ORM\JoinColumn line but that makes no difference. I can't seem to understand the issue... if you have further ideas, welcome!

Comment: well, I understood that what I intended to do is only supported by Doctrine 2.1, not by further versions... I have to use an Id and an extra foreign key to make it work. Can't be just one same column.